# Regex: Match a set of filenames separately from a string

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I have googled a lot, got multiple answers none working in my case. Sample string this regex should work on is

```
"Purging file summary_t.dat after pre_summary.csv, data.dat clogged"
```

Regex.Replace("regex", "$fileName") should give this

```
"Purging file $fileName after $fileName, $fileName clogged"
```

The regex's I have tried are

```
^[\w,\s-]+\.[A-Za-z]{3}$
```

It only matches the first filename

```
(?:[^\\:]+\\)*((?:[^:\\]+)\.\w+)
```

This one matches everything including text in between multiple filenames, so that I only get one $filename for the whole line

Note: The string is generic so I dont really know where I can get a filename in a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
(\w+\.\w+)
```

https://regex101.com/r/wK3cK7/1

Output:

```
MATCH 1
1.  [13-26] `summary_t.dat`
MATCH 2
1.  [33-48] `pre_summary.csv`
MATCH 3
1.  [50-58] `data.dat`
```

Answer (score 1):

This must work as well

```
\w+\.\w+
```

`\w  = Any letter, + = one or more, \. = followed by a dot (escape the . meaning, else only . means 0 or more)`
Here is the link for demo. http://regexr.com/3cu60

Comment: ▲ for remove [], my bad habit